# Submitting and displaying comments to a post

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm attempting to add basic comment functionality to posts.  I am able to display the form for comments, but once saved they do not appear under the post.  What I have so far:

## Comment Controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def create 
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = current_user.comments.build(comment_params)
    redirect_to [@topic, @post]

  end


  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
 end

end
```

## Post Controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @post = Post.find(params[:id]) 
    @comments = @post.comments 
  end
```

## Post Show View

```
<h1><%= markdown_to_html @post.title %></h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <small>
      <%= image_tag(@post.user.avatar.tiny.url) if @post.user.avatar? %>
      submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at) %> ago by
      <%= @post.user.name %>
    </small>
    <p><%= markdown_to_html( @post.body) %></p>
    <h2>Comments</h2>

    <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
    <%= render partial: 'comments/comment', locals: {comment: comment} %>
    <% end %>

    <%= render partial: 'comments/form', locals: {topic: @topic, post: @post} %>

  </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <% if policy(@post).edit? %>
        <%= link_to "Edit", edit_topic_post_path(@topic, @post), class: 'btn     btn-success' %>
      <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Comment Partial

```
<p><%= p comment.body %></p>
```

## Form Partial

```
<%= form_for [topic, post, post.comments.new] do |f| %>
<% if post.comments.new.errors.any? %>
<div class="alert alert-danger">
  <h4>There are <%= pluralize(post.errors.count, "error") %>.</h4>
  <ul>
    <%= post.comments.new.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<% end %>
<%= form_group_tag(post.comments.new.errors[:body]) do %>
<%= f.label :body %>
<%= f.text_area :body, rows: 1, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter     comment body" %>
<% end %>
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.submit "Save", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

I believe that should be all of the relevant code.  The functionality seems to be there, but I must be doing something wrong with the submission process.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you,

Matt

## Update

I added `validates :body, length: {minimum: 5}, presence: true` to the post model and `@comment = current_user.comments.create!(comment_params)` to the comment controller.

If I submit a comment form with <5 characters I do get the 'Validation failed: Body is too short (minimum is 5 characters)' message, but if the message meets the requirements it will submit and nothing will happen.

Comment: can you check on console, that data got saved correctly e.g. `post.comments` are there

Comment: I think your params don't match what you're expecting in the controller.  Have a look at the params in the log file.

Comment: @Matt - Congratulations on starting to learn Ruby! As an FYI, all your call to `post.comments.new.errors` in the view are not going to behave like you expect. If you create a new instance each time then you will never see any errors because it doesn't use the object that you are actually validating from the controller. In order to see validations errors you must use the same object from the controller (usually an `@comment` instance).

Comment: @carlosramireziii - You're right, I just realized that.  I'm currently working on solving that right now.  Thank you for your encouragement!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that you have associated the comment to a `User` with the following line

`current_user.comments.create(...)`

however nowhere do you associate the newly created comment to the `Post`. When you subsequently call `@post.comments`, you won't get the `Comment` back because it was never attached to that `Post`

Since you have access to the `@post` from within the `CommentsController`, I recommend doing something like this in your `create` action

```
def create
   # ...
   current_user.comments.create(comment_params_with_post)
   # ...
end

def comment_params_with_post
   comment_params.merge(post: @post)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You forget to save comment. Instead of:

```
@comment = current_user.comments.build(comment_params)
```

you should use

```
@comment = current_user.comments.create(comment_params)
```

> collection.build(attributes = {}, …)
>
> Returns one or more new objects of the collection type that have been instantiated with attributes and linked to this object through a foreign key, but have not yet been saved.

[Here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many) is more details.

Comment: Unfortunately using .create doesn't solve the issue, my posts still fail to update when I submit.  Is there another part of code you should see?

Comment: What does it mean 'fail'?? Required full backttrace of error.

Comment: I should not use the term "fail", but according to the console when I am submitting comments they must not be saving.  For example, when I save a comment to Post 44, Post.find(44).comments brings up nothing.

Comment: Try to replace `create` to `create!`. `create!` will raise validation exception if you have it. In this case you will have ability to investigate problem and fix it. FYI: `create` return validation error in `errors` field but doesn't raise error. [Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) is more details about validation.